# connectedAccessories returns empty array

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I'm using the following method to check whether my Bluetooth accessory is connected to my iPhone:

```
- (BOOL)checkAccessory {
    NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
    EAAccessory *selectedAccessory = nil;

    if ([accessories count]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [accessories count]; i++) {
             selectedAccessory = [accessories objectAtIndex:i];
            for (NSDictionary *tmpDict in accessories) {
                if ([[tmpDict valueForKey:@"manufacturer"] isEqualToString:@"FOO"]) {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I know `ExternalAccessory` framework only works with MFi device and I have all the needed protocols declared inside the Info.plist file.

This is working fine except in one case: when I restart the smartphone and launch my test app again, the `connectedAccessories` method returns zero accessories, even if the peripheral is turned on and connected to the iPhone (in the Bluetooth settings, the accessory appears connected and the Bluetooth icon in the status bar is active).

Could someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: What's the iOS version? Is it 9.x?

Comment: @realaboo Yes, it is.